# store chat history in xmpp server in ios application

Tags: ios, xmpp

Is there any way to save chat history to xmpp server permanently.
i.e if i uninstall the application and install it again i am able to restore all the chat from the server?

I am using below code :-

```
  XMPPMessageArchivingCoreDataStorage *_xmppMsgStorage = [XMPPMessageArchivingCoreDataStorage sharedInstance];

    NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [_xmppMsgStorage mainThreadManagedObjectContext];
    NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"XMPPMessageArchiving_Message_CoreDataObject"
                                                         inManagedObjectContext:moc];
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
    [request setEntity:entityDescription];
 //   [request setFetchLimit:20];

    NSError *error;
    NSString *predicateFrmt = @"bareJidStr == %@";
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:predicateFrmt, userJid];
    request.predicate = predicate;
    NSArray *messages = [moc executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
```

But in this case if i uninstall the application the messages get deleted.

Comment: You can save it in the KeyChain, then the data will be saved even if you delete the app. But saving lots of data in the keychain is not a good idea as it will be a bit slow.

Comment: @rckoenes thanks for the quick reply.Is there any other way to do this?Because keychain is helpful for storing username,password etc i.e limited number of data.I  need to save text,images,audio file etc

Comment: Not really, since the sandbox is delete if the app is delete. And since you can only save files within the sandbox. It might work if you save the log in iCloud, but again this is not really the optimal solution.

Comment: @rckoenes can we store the history by using API .But I am not able to understand  which format should i store the data or send the data to API ?

Comment: That depends on the API.